# Shaded region up to the end of frame with Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

Using Matplotlib I am trying to shade the region y > N, with N some number.
The problem is that I am not able to have the shaded region going to the end of the frame.
Here is a simple example.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

x = [i for i in range(0,100,10)]

ax.plot(x,x,'-o')

N=110
ylim = max(ax.get_ylim())
ax.axhspan(N,ylim,alpha=.5)

plt.show()
```

The result is this:

[image]

How to have the shaded region not stopping, but arriving up to the end of the frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ax.autoscale()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.autoscale.html) can come in handy here. Default, matplotlib automatically adapts the limits of the axes every time something is added. Normally also some padding is added to leave some free space above and below (and left and right).

Calling `ax.autoscale(enable=True, axis='y', tight=True)` changes this behavior for the y-axis, forcing "tight" limits, so without padding.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = [i for i in range(0, 100, 10)]
ax.plot(x, x, '-o')

N = 110
ylim1 = max(ax.get_ylim())
ax.autoscale(enable=True, axis='y', tight=True)
ax.axhspan(N, ylim1, alpha=.5)

plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Alternatively, you could collect the limits before calling `axhspan` and setting them manually afterwards:

```py
ax.plot(x, x, '-o')
N = 110
ylim0, ylim1 = ax.get_ylim()
ax.axhspan(N, ylim1, alpha=.5)
ax.set_ylim(ylim0, max(N, ylim1))
```